# Flutter (the doctor check crashed): Exception: Could not find file at

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

I was trying to set up flutter on VScode but saw a bunch of errors when I ran "flutter doctor". Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
[☠] Flutter (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this
      issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Exception: Could not find file at
      /private/var/folders/rp/d215zkfs31jcv19jk55421200000gn/T/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/resources/devtools/version.json
```

[image]

Comment: First of all first share the output of flutter doctor -v for more logs. and seems like not path set for android sdk as well